# returning a struct of queries

Tags: coldfusion

If a series of queries are created like so:

```
<cfloop list="#platform_list#" index="x">
    <cfquery name="#trim(x)#" dbtype="query">
        <!--- stuff to build the query --->
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

and I then return the queries in a struct like so:

```
<cfset queries_RET = StructNew() />
<cfloop list="#platform_list#" index="x">
    <cfif StructKeyExists(args, #trim(x)#)>
        <!--- here's where I think things go horribly wrong --->
        <cfset queries_RET[x] = #x# />
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfreturn queries_RET />
```

And then when returned to the calling function as "graphData", I try to access it like so:

```
<cfloop list="#platform_list#" index="x">
    <cfif StructKeyExists(url, x) and StructKeyExists(graphData, x)>
        <cfloop query="graphData[x]">
```

I get an error at the last line:

```
Attribute validation error for tag cfloop.
The value of the attribute query, which is currently graphData[x], is invalid.
```

The value of the struct at graphData[x] is a string having the same value as the element name... so what do I do to assign the query with that name instead? I'm sure it's ridiculously obvious. :(

**EDIT**:

I'll give the answer to Shawn, although I finally figured out what my underlying issue(s) are. First, I didn't realize that

```
<cfset queries_RET[x] = #x# />
```

doesn't actually assign the query to the element at x, but instead a reference to it. To assign the actual query object, I need to do this:

```
<cfset queries_RET[x] = #Evaluate(x)# />
```

Second, when the struct is returned to the calling function, calling

```
<cfloop list="#Application.platform_list#" index="x">
    <cfloop query="#graphData[x]#">
```

didn't work because the query attribute of cfloop is looking for a **reference** to a query object --- and the query object it was looking for didn't exist since it hadn't been returned.

Finally, now that I am actually returning a valid query object, that query attribute still doesn't work, because now graphData[x] isn't a reference. To make it work, I have to first assign a reference, and use that as the query attribute in the cfloop:

```
<cfloop list="#Application.platform_list#" index="x">
    <cfset thisQuery = #graphData[x]#>
    <cfloop query="thisQuery">
```

I think that my fundamental problem was not understanding the the query attribute isn't an actual query object, but a *reference* to one instead. It's been a learning curve!

Comment: To clarify some verbiage you used above, the syntax <cfset x = evaluate(y) /> doesn't assign a reference; Y is expected to be a string, and is converted into the value of the variable whose name matches the string Y. Y is still a string, however--both in your example above, and in the answer below (ie. 'query_a')--and it is that string that ultimately is passed to the loop. Furthermore, the assignment isn't a reference because changing X after assignment doesn't affect Y. In short, you've re-iterated the answer, but with an extra Evaluate() step that isn't necessary in the context of a cfloop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<CFLOOP>` query attribute takes the name of a query (string), not an actual query object.

When you pass something into that attribute, CF expects it to be a string.

If it's a literal, CF will expect it to be the name of a valid query.

If it's a variable, CF will expect the value of the variable to be *equal to the name* of the query.

Therefore, the output you ultimately want is:

```
<cfloop list="#platform_list#" index="x">
    <cfloop query="#x#">
```

Here is a full snippet of code that confirms this, which you may refer to/compare to for your own code:

```
<cfset query_a = QueryNew('id,name,pass') />
<cfset QueryAddRow(query_a)>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query_a,'id',1)>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query_a,'name','joe')>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query_a,'pass','joe123')>

<cfset query_b = QueryNew('id,name,pass') />
<cfset QueryAddRow(query_b)>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query_b,'id',4)>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query_b,'name','pete')>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query_b,'pass','pete123')>

<cfset query_c = QueryNew('id,name,pass') />
<cfset QueryAddRow(query_c)>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query_c,'id',7)>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query_c,'name','frank')>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query_c,'pass','frank123')>

<cfset platform_list = 'query_a,query_b,query_c' />

<cfloop list="#platform_list#" index="x">
    <cfloop query="#x#">
        <cfoutput>#id# #name# #pass#</cfoutput><br/>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

You'll notice in this snippet that if you change the  query attribute back to "x" (rather than #x#) you'll produce the exact same error you are encountering now.

Why?

Answer: platform_list is a comma-delimited list of strings (which x becomes via the loop), not a comma-delimited list of Query objects.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<cfloop list="#platform_list#" index="x">
    <cfif StructKeyExists(url, x) and StructKeyExists(graphData, url[x])>
        <cfset q = graphData[x]>
        <cfloop query="q">
```

If this throws

> The value of the attribute query, which is currently q, is invalid

Then you should cfdump the q make sure it is a query object.

Comment: Indeed. CFLOOP seems to like its query names to be "simple".

Comment: That gives the error: " The value of the attribute query, which is currently q, is invalid."

Comment: Yeah, I think that the assignment is the problem... any ideas on that end?

Comment: Use your basic debug skills like `<CFDUMP>`, on `queries_RET` and go all the way up and see where the problem is.